# Julia-lang containing big "matrix of functions" can not compile

Tags: matrix, compilation, julia, jit

I have written a function in Julia, which contains a matrix whose dimension is 10*10. Each element of the matrix is a function of the input of the big function. 
For example,

```
function MATRIX(a::Float64,b::Float64,c::Float64,d::Float64,e::Float64)
   A = [A_11 A_12.... A_110
        A_21 A_22.... A_210  
          ...
        A_101 ........A_1010]
end
```

with A_ij a VERY LONG function of a, b, c, d, e.

When I say "VERY LONG" I mean, well, the .txt file which contains the matrix A weights more than 10Mb.

Under such a circumstance, I found that when I assigned values for a,b,c,d,e, and tried to run the function MATRIX, the cell in the Jupyter notebook just becomes stuck.

I do not know why. Maybe due to the Just-In-Time compiler of Julia? Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show code that reproduces this fully (like using random data or similar)? Difficult to debug with this much info. Also be useful to know if the notebooks starts to use up a lot of memory (RAM) or similar?

Comment: Why don't you provide a minimal working example? Or some insight into how you read/parse these `.txt` files to get the corresponding matrix elements? And by the way, I do not think the title reflects your problem --- you claim that `A_ij` are `function`s, but the title says they are `Symbol`s.

Comment: Arda You are right.

Comment: Alexander, I do not know if this is an issue with RAM. Maybe. However, in contrast to what Arda thought, I didn't "read" any expression from a txt file, instead each element of the matrix, for example, A_11 was copied into the the jupyter-notebook to form the final big matrix A.  The expression of A_11, was so long (more than 10000 characters) to be posed online. You can think it as a combination of algebraic/trigonometric function of function input (a.b.c.d.e)   .

Comment: @ZejiangWang we can only do some guess work _unless_ you provide some meaningful error/output from `julia`. Maybe you can try running these in the REPL. Blindly, I would like to guess, for the last time, that you might have some sort of [inference](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/labels/inference) labeled problem --- if you have long function calls on untyped function parameters, maybe the JIT is hanging. I think more experienced people should chime in, or you should maybe report it to the issue board of Julia.